# What are the criteria for the number of controller objects in a Cocoa Mac OS X app?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, architecture

I am learning Mac OS X development, and from reading different articles and Aaron Hillegass' book, it seems that MVC is the recommended design pattern to be used in Mac-based apps.

However, I could not find any instruction as to how when should we introduce a controller class/object and how many we should use.

So my question is:

Do we normally have one, or more than one, controller classes in a Cocoa-based Mac OS X app?
If we have more than one, what is the criteria for introducing a new controller class? How do the controller classes interact among themselves, or do they not and there is no need for such interaction?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Hillegass covers that; keep reading.  It's not an issue really.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Not necessarily true. There's no way any one book *can* directly answer Ahmed's question because the "correct" architecture for a given application depends entirely on that application.

Comment: I don't think the vote to close is fair. This is an important consideration and a potentially complicated issue. A developer's design choices early on directly affect how easily a mature application can be grown and maintained. +1 for a good question.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi - I can't really do anything about the close votes now, but if the question does get closed and you feel it is unjust, flag again and we can look at reopening it. In the meantime, I cleaned up the wording a bit which might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is partly a matter of making the application easy to understand, keeping the code organized, and somewhat a matter of personal taste.

A simple application like AddressBook.app could get away with a single controller-layer object. This object could manage the user's interaction with people and groups. Then again, it might have a Person controller and a Group controller, each of which will coordinate interaction between their respective pieces of UI (Group UI to Group controller, etc.) and the data containers (the list of groups and the list of people and, when viewing groups, the list of people that belong to that group). If you're bothering to go this far, you might have a *window controller* in which to stash the code that isn't specific to groups or people. That is, perhaps the code that manages reconfiguring the UI between Group and Person mode would go in the window controller of the window that contains this UI.

A complex application might have **MANY** controllers. It may have a controller for each window, the windows may own controllers for each instance of a self-contained set of controls dedicated to one aspect of the application. It may have controllers to manage non-UI items as well (network connections/downloads, user session, physical state of an attached peripheral, etc.). It really *truly* depends on your application and design needs.

Application architecture is an under-emphasized aspect of software development. Choosing *and maintaining* a good architecture over the lifetime of an application can sometimes mean the difference between "we can add this feature in a day" and "we'll have to completely rewrite some/half/most of the app to be able to add *anything* like this feature". It's part science and part art and simply takes experience (and an eye kept open to the architecture of your favorite open source projects as examples).

A critical thing to remember is this: The controller layer is the layer most specific to your app (and usually the least reusable part - purposefully-reusable controllers like NSArrayController not withstanding). It's what makes your app *your app*. Its model may be reusable to other apps and its views as well, but the controller layer is the "soul" of your app.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer for me to get started, has cleared a lot ambuguities from my mind :)